# W1 + W3 = W2 + W3. Then W1 = W2

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, vector-spaces, alternative-proof

***Claim*.** Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$, and suppose that $W_1, W_2,$ and $W_3$ are subspaces
of $V$ such that $W_1 + W_3 = W_2 + W_3.$ Then $W_1 = W_2.$

***Proof***

$W_1 + W_3 - W_3 = W_2 + W_3 - W_3$

$\therefore$ $W_1 = W_2$

My proof feels like cheating, is it even valid? Also is there anyway to 'say', prove or demonstrate the same thing in a more rigorous way i.e. set builder notation?

In regards to the rules of the site is my question to simple, if so what can I do to make it better?

Comment: Subtraction between subspaces of a vector space is not defined.

Comment: Your claim is clearly false: $\{0\}+V=V+V$, for every vector space $V$. If your claim is true, it implies that every vector space just consists of the zero vector. Your attempt at a proof is essentially the same as concluding that $1=2$ from the fact that $1\cdot0=2\cdot0$ and multiplying both sides by $0^{-1}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $V=\mathbb{R}^2 $ and $W_3= \{(x,0) : x\in \mathbb{R}\}$, $W_1= \{(0,y) : y\in \mathbb{R}\}$ and $W_2= \{(t,t) : t\in \mathbb{R}\}$

You should be able to verify that $W_1+W_3 = W_2 + W_3$

What does that tell you about your claim?

Comment: Does it say that the claim is false?

Answer (score 3):

There is a very simple counterexample. Since the statement is about arbitrary subspaces $W_1$, $W_2$ and $W_3$ only subject to the condition that $W_1+W_3=W_2+W_3$, it should in particular hold for $W_1=\{0\}$, $W_2=W_3=V$. Then from
$$
\{0\}+V=V+V
$$
(which is true), you'd conclude that
$$
\{0\}=V
$$
Now any non trivial vector space is a counterexample.

From a slightly higher point of view, the set $\mathscr{L}(V)$ of subspaces of $V$ is a commutative monoid under the $+$ operation, because it is associative and has the neutral element $\{0\}$, because $\{0\}+W=W$, for every $W\in\mathscr{L}(V)$.

However, this monoid cannot be cancellative (that is $W_1+W_3=W_2+W_3$ implies $W_1=W_2$) for several reasons, the most important one being that it has an *absorbing element*, namely $V$:
$$
W+V=V
$$
for every $W\in\mathscr{L}(V)$. An absorbing element cannot have a symmetric element, unless the monoid is trivial.

Also, if $U$ is a subspace of $V$ and $\mathscr{L}(V;\subseteq U)$ denotes the set of subspaces of $V$ contained in $U$, we have $\mathscr{L}(V;\subseteq U)=\mathscr{L}(U)$, which is thus a submonoid of $\mathscr{L}(V)$. Since every $U\in\mathscr{L}(V)$ is the absorbing element in a submonoid, no element can have a symmetric element, except for $\{0\}$.

*Note.* By “symmetric element” of an element $x$ in a monoid $(M,*,e)$ I mean an element $y$ such that $x*y=y*x=e$.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but essentially what you are saying is that since addition isn't always 'symmetric' i.e. W+V=V we cannot use inverse operations like subtraction without a prior knowledge of the sets we are dealing with, because inverse operations imply or assume symmetry.

Comment: Is "symmetric element" the same as "inverse element", or is there more to what you're saying?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yes, I used “symmetric” to be agnostic about the operation being denoted additively or multiplicatively. I added a note.

Comment: @egreg: Okay. (However, in my experience "inverse" too is used for both additively and multiplicatively notated monoids).

Answer (score 2):

What does your claim say if $W_3$ is the whole space $V$?

You can't subtract subspaces.

Comment: Thank you, but that only answers one component of my question, may you elaborate on you answer.

Comment: @oypus This answer answers your question completely.

Comment: SInce your claim is false, there is no way to "demonstrate the same thing in a more rigorous way".Your notation is fine. Better notation would not make the claim true.